# Using P&T Assets with Multi Site Manager (MSM)

Tags: assets, file-uploads, multi-site-manager

I have Assets set up for Site #1. I've added Site #2, and I would like it, and Site #3, etc., to share the same Assets folders.

I've read through the Assets documentation, but cannot find any reference to Multi Site Manager.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I'm happy to add settings in config.php.

Comment: For now, I've set up duplicate folder (references) for site #2. In other words, for site #2, Assets is managing the same folders as site #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it can't be done. See my comment above for alternate solution.